# ImageOptimization in Rails 5 ActiveStorage

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm planning to upgrade Rails to 5.2 in one of my websites and introduce ActiveStorage, as of right now I use Paperclip with paperclip_optimizer. One of the negative sides is that I will lose the optimizer, when replacing paperclip with ActiveStorage. How can I implement automatically image optimization on user uploads in ActiveStorage?

Comment: What do you mean by image optimisation? Because activestorage supports all transformations that minimagick does, so you can easily resize, crop, remove metadata, change sampling, reduce quality, etc. It does not run on uploads, but you can either trigger it with a job or let the images be lazily generated when they are needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible by creating a custom Variation. There is a good example here:

https://prograils.com/posts/rails-5-2-active-storage-new-approach-to-file-uploads

Answer (score 1):

If you are on AWS you can create Lambda function that can listen to an S3 bucket for uploads, and runs image optimization on the newly uploaded files.

Comment: Note that ActiveStorage does save the intial blob's checksum. The docs also explicitly state: "Blobs are intended to be immutable". Changing the data from outside may invite some sort of mayhem.

Answer (score 0):

Active Storage doesn’t have built-in support for optimizing images on upload.

Comment: Maybe, I formulated my question a bit wrong. I know there is not a optimizer in ActiveStorage, but how are everyone handling optimization when using ActiveStorage? Must be someone, who has upgraded and implemented some sort of solution that I could mimic in some way!